# Modify Stored Procedure Without Executing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure that fires off a thousand emails. It's auto-run at 1 AM every night. I have to edit the stored procedure in Management Studio: I know I have to choose "Modify" and then make the edits, but I don't want to click "Execute" to save it, or the emailing sequence will start. How can I save the new code without executing the stored procedure? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Clicking `Execute` doesn't execute the procedure itself, it executes only SQL command altering the procedure.

You can check it by creating some mock stored procedure that is meant to just add some data to table and check if it adds that data when you click `Execute` in `Modify` window.

Comment: Much appreciated - I'm grateful for your help

Answer (score 3):

Clicking Execute won't actually run the procedure, it just applies your modifications.

Comment out the part that triggers the emails to be sent then execute, if you would prefer to see what it does first. Then when you are comfortable, uncomment and make your changes.

Comment: Much appreciated - I'm grateful for your help